# Compile one file in QT Creator

Tags: qt-creator

How to compile only one file from project in QT creator.
Is there a hotkey?
For example in VS you can press Ctrl F7 and compile your current cpp file.

Answer (score 10):

It is now possible to do it, since at least Qt Creator 2.8.1.

Use `Build->Build file <filename>` or the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+B</kbd>:

[image]

Or right click on a file in the project view, and there is a Build item in the context menu that builds just that file:

[image]

You can track the feature request or vote for it at https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-106.

Comment: Now it is 2013. This feature is still not available? it is useful.

Comment: I think it is solved.(https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTCREATORBUG-106). But I still can not find how to do it...

Comment: @SANDSOFTIME - You can right-click on a file in the projects mode and have it built.

Comment: Note: this does not work with CMake in QtCreator (v4.4.0)

Comment: This works by clicking from the menu, but does not work with shortcut. I changed it from Ctrl+Alt+B to Ctrl+Alt+C, it works now.

Answer (score 1):

Normally if you hit `CTRL + B`, Qt Creator will call `make`, which will in turn compile any files that have been modified since you compiled the last time. AFAIK there is no designated key for re-building the current file.

However, all Keystrokes can be configured in the application preferences `General -> Keyboard`. There are also a number of interesting other commands you might find useful.